# Strip method at Python doesn't clear all

Tags: python, string, strip

i have some problem to strip '[' at my string (read from file).
code

```
data = open(Koorpath1,'r')
for x in data:
    print(x)    
    print(x.strip('['))
```

result

> [["0.9986130595207214","26.41608428955078"],["39.44521713256836","250.2412109375"],["112.84327697753906","120.34269714355469"],["260.63800048828125","15.424667358398438"],["273.6199645996094","249.74160766601562"]]
>
> "0.9986130595207214","26.41608428955078"],["39.44521713256836","250.2412109375"],["112.84327697753906","120.34269714355469"],["260.63800048828125","15.424667358398438"],["273.6199645996094","249.74160766601562"]]

Desired output :

> "0.9986130595207214","26.41608428955078","39.44521713256836","250.2412109375","112.84327697753906","120.34269714355469","260.63800048828125","15.424667358398438","273.6199645996094","249.74160766601562"

Thanks

Comment: `strip` removes characters *at the start or end of the string* only. Looks like it does exactly what it's supposed to. If you want to remove characters in the middle as well, you need `replace`. But really, what for? This looks like JSON and you should probably `json.loads` it.

Comment: it's all string "[[ ... ]]". Type <class 'str'>

Comment: What is your desired output ?

Comment: @deceze Oh thanks, yes it's json data that i dump (save) at a file.Any suggest ?

Comment: @Hearner like that "0.9986130595207214","26.41608428955078","39.44521713256836","250.2412109375","112.84327697753906","120.34269714355469","260.63800048828125","15.424667358398438","273.6199645996094","249.74160766601562"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It strips the first two '[', it seems you have one long string, you have to split it first.

```
datalist = data.split[',']
for x in datalist:
    # code here
```

If you don't want to split it and have it all in one string you need replace not strip (strip only works at the end and the beginning.

```
data = data.replace('[','')
```

Comment: data = data.replace('[','') using replace work. Thankyou very much.

Comment: Glad I could help, if that solves your problem you should probably mark the answer as correct to "close" the question.

Answer (score 0):

If the data is JSON, then parse it into a Python list and treat it from there:

```
from itertools import chain
import json

nums = json.loads(x)
print(','.join('"%s"' % num for num in chain.from_iterable(nums)))
```

`chain.from_iterable` helps you "flatten" the list of lists and `join` concatenates everything into one long output.

Comment: yes, it'is data json and i save it at a file. (i couldn't access the json data (API)). Thanks anyway